# How to add gradient border to a text in css (or scss/sass)

Tags: css, text, sass, gradient

It is possible to add **gradient border to a text** **without SVG** in CSS/Sass?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a way to do it, you realize that it works with webkit and that kills the compatibility with browsers that are not modern.

```css
body { padding: 50px; }

h1 {
    font: 100px sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    
    /* Warning: no fallback */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, red, blue);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 4px transparent;
    color: white; /* same as background */
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS</h1>
```

Comment: I would add to this that including `@support` rule may be a good idea to not have the text go invisible (white on white). using this rule, you can chose to add additional styling to be added only when a modern browser supports it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@supports